# Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater.I am using java 16.0

Tags: cordova, vuejs2

I have start to create a moblie app using vue,cordova. I have no previous experience in app development.I have setup a project using below link.

https://morioh.com/p/8552af6d3fd8

My java version : java version "16.0.2"

Cordova version : 10

When i try to run npm run android got below error.

Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cordova 10 still pins cordova-android 9, which requires java 8.

You can install cordova-android 10, which removed that requirement (but still, java 16 has problems, you should downgrade to at least 15)

In your project run

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@latest
```